# Access to label data from detailview of different cells (I use Core Data)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uitableview

This is my situation: I have a table viewcontroller and I use core data so each cell created by user goes to a detail view with different data.

For example, taking the data of a label in a detail of a cell 4, and the label data from the detail in cell 5, and so on

My idea is to make something with this data from each information of each cell and show it in my "home" window.

MY QUESTION: How to take the information of the label of the detail of each cell created by user, and put it another place?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use labels and other UI elements to store data. Instead, set the UI elements to reflect data that is stored in an underlying model of some kind.

If you model the data, you can access the underlying data model from any view and you don't need to read values from UI elements from other views.

This is a standard approach of the [MVC design pattern](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MVC.html) used in Cocoa.

Comment: @user2411480, I just added a link that helps explain the concept. If you need further help, please explain the problem in more detail in your question. Where are you getting stuck? Show some code. You shouldn't have an issue creating any view you want from the data.

Comment: for example, i have an atribute called age, each cell created, in teh detail have the age text label. How do i access to age from cell 1, age from cell 2, and so on, from anotehr view, like homeviewcontroller